# Raspbian Motion start and stop

Tags: motion

The start of application Motion (use by camera to detect a detection); i use this command:

```
sudo motion
```

How can i stop motion please?

Thank you .

Comment: your question is not related to the Raspberry Pi in any way .... it is a Linux question ... in the future, please post your question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: `sudo killall motion`

Comment: Hi jsotola, this is related to raspi because a lot of people use it, and I'm not able to get good search results by searching for "stop motion".

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop any program started from the commandline.

Comment: I want to stop on a bash script

Comment: @juju Please add this important information to your question.